# bootstrap: non responsive page format

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

in my below code i have page designed using bootstrap html and CSS but it is not looking good on all devices for ex on mobile ... grid looks very zoomed and not responsive i itried to remove  `grid-template-columns: auto auto;` it worked but i need to view 2 columns in each row .. is it bootstrap problem or way i wrote code is not the right way of responsivness?
any help please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWalg.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link href="assets/js/scripts.js" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"> </script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
  .navbar {
    background-color: rgb(43, 59, 43) !important;
  }

  .h2,
  h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
  }
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .grid-container>div {
    /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 59%;">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a href="menu.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">menu</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">about </a>


        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="CardController">
    <div class="grid-container" id="menu-items-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


</body>

</html>
<script>


  products = [
    {
      "placeImage": "assets/images/item.png",
      "placeName": " salad  ",
      "price": 80
    },
    {
      "placeImage": "assets/images/item.png",
      "placeName": " salad ",
      "price": 65
    },
    {
      "placeImage": "assets/images/item.png",
      "placeName": "   salad ",
      "price": 30
    }

  ];
  console.log(products);
  const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));

  function renderItem(item) {
    const base = document.createElement("div");
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const title = document.createElement("h1");
    const price = document.createElement("h2");

    img.src = item.placeImage;
    title.textContent = item.placeName;
    price.textContent = item.price;

    base.appendChild(img);
    base.appendChild(title);
    base.appendChild(price);

    return base;
  }

  const container = document.querySelector("#menu-items-container");
  for (let item of data) {
    container.appendChild(renderItem(item));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you add "Media Queries" to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just needed to add `.ms-auto` to `.navbar-nav` and the navbar is now in the right place?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link href="assets/js/scripts.js" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"> </script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
  .navbar {
    background-color: rgb(43, 59, 43) !important;
  }

  .h2,
  h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
  }
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .grid-container>div {
    /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: auto;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo Here" style="width: 59%;">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <a href="menu.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">menu</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">home</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">about </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="CardController">
    <div class="grid-container" id="menu-items-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


</body>

</html>
<script>
  products = [
    {
      "placeImage": "assets/images/item.png",
      "placeName": " salad  ",
      "price": 80
    },
    {
      "placeImage": "assets/images/item.png",
      "placeName": " salad ",
      "price": 65
    },
    {
      "placeImage": "assets/images/item.png",
      "placeName": "   salad ",
      "price": 30
    }

  ];
  console.log(products);
  const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));

  function renderItem(item) {
    const base = document.createElement("div");
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const title = document.createElement("h1");
    const price = document.createElement("h2");

    img.src = item.placeImage;
    title.textContent = item.placeName;
    price.textContent = item.price;

    base.appendChild(img);
    base.appendChild(title);
    base.appendChild(price);

    return base;
  }

  const container = document.querySelector("#menu-items-container");
  for (let item of data) {
    container.appendChild(renderItem(item));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, i edited question up the problem  is with grid view when i removed ` grid-template-columns: auto auto;` it worked but it show me one colum and i need to view 2 columns